# Can you activate a T-Flip Flop without a button in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to build a rail track switcher for a T intersection, and I'd like it to be activated automatically when I ride over detector rails.  I have two tracks, each with their own detector rail, with a redstone circuit leading into the upper dropper of a dropper/hopper T-Flip Flop.

The T Flip Flop part works - if I press a button on the back of the top dropper, it switches the track around.  I'm wondering why I can't activate the T Flip Flop using detector rails.  Will it only work with a button?  It seems like every video or article I can find includes a button, so that might be my answer right there.

I'm still a little new to redstone circuits, so forgive me if this seems like a dumb question.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Some screenshots would help. It should definitely work with whatever input you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pulse generator with a comparator in subtract mode and a repeater in powering the side with both the comparator and repeater having the same input, or you could use a T-flip-flop that has a pulse generator attached like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6D9_hXL0VU&t=275s)

Answer (score -1):

To activate a T Flip Flop using detector rails, you need to ensure that the redstone signal from the detector rail is strong enough to power the T Flip Flop circuit. Detector rails emit a weak redstone signal, so you may need to amplify it using a redstone repeater or a redstone torch.

Here's a step-by-step guide to activating the T Flip Flop with detector rails:

- Connect the output of the detector rail to a redstone repeater or a redstone torch.
- Ensure that the redstone signal is strong enough to power the T Flip Flop circuit by placing the repeater/torch near the T Flip Flop circuit or using additional redstone repeaters to amplify the signal.
- Connect the output of the repeater/torch to the activation point of the T Flip Flop circuit (the back of the top dropper in your case).

By doing this, the redstone signal from the detector rail will be amplified and able to trigger the T Flip Flop, allowing it to switch the track automatically when you ride over the detector rail.